# I am using wordpress prepare, cannot use IN( array), mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Look at my code, since I use wordpress prepare, so implode array did not work for me. I figure out the problem. I cannot put one $args in the query. Let say, if I have three %s, I need to put like $args,$args,$args. Therefore, I would like ask you any way to solve this problem? Please don't remove $wpdb->prepare, because it is for security purpose, correct me if i'm wrong. Because I have to use %s, so there's an issue.

```html
<?php
$arg = array('a','b','c');
$que= implode(',', array_fill(0, $arg, '%s'));

$args = implode(',', $arg);

$sym = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
 SELECT DISTINCT disease FROM dis WHERE disease IN ($que)
 ",$args));//the problem is that if there are three %s, I need to put $args,$args,$args
print_r($sym);//echo nothing
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any error output?

Comment: no error output, it just echo nothing.

Comment: WHERE FIND_IN_SET(disease, $que)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$arg = array('a','b','c');
$que= implode(',', array_fill(0, 3, '%s') );

$sym = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT disease FROM dis WHERE disease IN ($que)
    ",$arg));

print_r($sym);
```

Please see : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php